# Animation nodes: multiples of a collection with animation along a curve plus lattice modifiers

Tags: modifiers, animation-nodes, collections, instances, lattice

I have a collection... inside that collection is a curve, and an object with two modifiers (curve, and lattice)
the object runs through a simple 30 frame animation.
By using animation nodes, I would like to create an array of say 20, that follow an axis (x) but I would like to stagger the animation of each item in the array in succession. that is first instance animates, then 5 frames later (random number) the following instance begins its animation.
also extra credit to take that array and duplicate it as a mirror to the original along the y axis.

(bottom image: here is what I want... an just duplicated the collections and mirrored and staggered... but the problem is that they all animate at the same place in the timeline. I need to have control over when the next one begins.

cheers

[image: this is the file structure]

[image: here is what I want... an just duplicated the collections and mirrored and staggered... but the problem is that they all animate at the same place in the timeline. I need to have control over when the next one begins.]